# Integrate a function over this set

Tags: definite-integrals

Problem: if $X$ is an infinite measure subset of $\mathbb R$ and $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a continuous function integrable over $X$ and all its translations and rotations, is $f$ integrable over $\mathbb R$?

Trying to find a counterexample, I came up with this:

- $a_n=b_{n-1}+1$,
- $b_n=a_n+\frac1n$,
- $b_0=-1$,
- $X=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty(a_n,b_n)$.

Does $\int_Xe^xdx$ converges? ---edit: no it doesn't

Is there any easy counterexample?

Comment: I’m pretty sure, it does not since $\exp$ increases way faster than $X$ loses mass as you walk right. Maybe you’ll have better luck with $\mathrm{e}^{-x}$, though? – Oh, wait. That’ll count as a rotation, wouldn’t it?

Comment: @k.stm Yes it's a rotation of the set, sorry :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said before, it does not converge since $a_n ≥ 0$ for all $n ∈ ℕ$ and so $\exp|_X ≥ 1$. Therefore $∫_X \mathrm{e}^x dx ≥ ∫_X  dx = ∞$.

Okay, so the idea is to use the divergence of $Σ_n \frac 1 n$ vs. the convergence of $Σ_n \frac 1 {n^2}$.

Let $f \colon ℝ → [0..1],\, x ↦ \min\{1,\frac 1 {|x|}\}$ and $X = \bigcup_{k ∈ ℤ} I_k$, where $I_k$ is the interval of reals bewteen $k$ and $k+\tfrac{1}{k}$. Then $∫_ℝ f(x)dx = ∞$ and $∫_X f(x)dx \approx \sum_n \frac{1}{n^2} < ∞$, and this probably won’t change with translations or reflections. Now, I cannot give you a proof of this without investing too much time because I am not good at analysis, but I’m very certain that this works out. I hope that helps.

(If you can work this out, I would like to see the full argument.)

Comment: Sorry, I tried thrice coming up with a counterexample, but each time I was missing some condition.

Comment: Sorry, I upvoted the answer but changed the question, thank you anyway.

Comment: @izabera Okay, I added my idea of a counterexample, but I am not able to carry out the details and I am not absolutely sure that this works out. But I have great hopes for it.